# Add slide-out menu to TabBarController in Swift (with UIScrollView)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller, slide

I have an application, completely written in code so no storyboards, which sets the  rootViewController in the AppDelegate to TabBarController. This is a custom class of UITabBarController which sets up all views, adds the corresponding ViewControllers inside and sets a NavigationController for each ViewController.

```
// didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

let MainScreen = TabBarController()
self.window?.rootViewController = MainScreen
```

Now, it all works, but I want to add a slide-out menu from the left to display a couple of settings. I want a button on the main screen on the left (inside the NavigationController) and when I click it, I want the menu to slide in, pushing the current ViewController to the right accordingly. A great example is when you click your own profile picture on the top left side of the feed in Twitter.

I thought about a couple of ways to implement this, have read a lot online and seen examples, which often use third party plugins or storyboards, which I don't want. Other examples seem to work but not with a TabBarController.

I would like to use a UIScrollView to accomplish this by setting the contentSize to 1.5 times the UIScreen width, opening the app launches to x-value of half the screen width so the ViewController is shown, then on tapping the button the x-value changes to 0 to show the menu. That's the plan. However, I seem unable to add the TabBarController (which is not a UIView but a UITabBarController) to my SlideController (custom UIViewController with UIScrollViewDelegate). Any suggestions how I can implement this? This is my SlideController, which will become my RootViewController, so far:

```
import UIKit

class SlideController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        view.addSubview(scrollableView)
        scrollableView.delegate = self

    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        print("scroll to: x ", scrollView.contentOffset.x, " y ", scrollView.contentOffset.y)

    }

    var scrollableView: UIScrollView = {

        let scrollableView = UIScrollView()
        let scrollableWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width + (UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5)
        scrollableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        scrollableView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollableWidth, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        scrollableView.backgroundColor = .white
        scrollableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
        scrollableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        scrollableView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
        scrollableView.alwaysBounceVertical = true

        return scrollableView

    }()

}
```

Basically, what I want to ask is: how can I add the UITabBarController that is my current rootViewController to the UIScrollView? Secondly, is this a great idea or are there other solutions that might work better? Open to all suggestions and ideas.

Cheers guys!